# Configure logging time in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Can the logging time be configured in JMeter ? On default the total transactions data is written every 30 seconds in jmeter.log file .

Comment: what you want to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure [interval](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Generate_Summary_Results)  in jmeter.properties property `summariser.interval`:

> jmeter.properties file for the summariser configuration items

> interval between summaries (in seconds) default 3 minutes

> #summariser.interval=30